# WCF Soap response is wrapping properties

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

This WCF response seems to be wrapping the property `WhoAmIResult` more than once.

Response:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <WhoAmIResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <WhoAmIResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Service" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <a:WhoAmIResult>your name here</a:WhoAmIResult>
         </WhoAmIResult>
      </WhoAmIResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Expectation:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <WhoAmIResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <a:WhoAmIResult>your name here</a:WhoAmIResult>
      </WhoAmIResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Here's the code behind:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    WhoAmIResponse WhoAmI(string s);
}

[DataContract]
public class WhoAmIResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public string WhoAmIResult { get; set; }
}

public class Service : IService
{
    public WhoAmIResponse WhoAmI(string s)
    {
        return new WhoAmIResponse
        {
            WhoAmIResult = s
        };
    }
}
```

I just can't figure out what I need to do to get to this response, without exceeding wrappers. I must not have `WhoAmIResult` twice in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I took out the namespace as @STORM told me to, I've got this response:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">    
  <s:Body>
    <WhoAmIResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
       <WhoAmIResult xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
          <WhoAmIResult xmlns="">your name result</WhoAmIResult>
       </WhoAmIResult>
    </WhoAmIResponse>    
  </s:Body> 
</s:Envelope>
```

The namespace wasn't there but there was still the wrapper.

After some experiments I noticed that `WhoAmIResult` could be the name of a string response not a object. So I removed `WhoAmIResponse` object and put a simple string response. The code ended up like this:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public string WhoAmI(string s)
    {
        return s;
    }
}
```

And now I get the expected response:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <WhoAmIResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <WhoAmIResult>your name result</WhoAmIResult>
      </WhoAmIResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The problem was that I didn't need to declare another object to give the answer. There seems to be a convention for the response XML like `[MethodName]Response` and `[MethodName]Result`.

Thanks @STORM, I'm ashamed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting setting Namespace to empty

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class WhoAmIResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public string WhoAmIResult { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Now I get this:

`<WhoAmIResult xmlns="">?</WhoAmIResult>`

But the rest is the same.It is still wrapping WhoAmIResult property inside another 'phantom' object with the same name.